# Hide / Show header on scroll effect jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to implement this https://www.invisionapp.com/ header on scroll effect but can't make it work.

I tried this

```
  jQuery(window).scroll(function () { 
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() < 200) {
      jQuery('header').hide();
    } else {
      jQuery('header').show();
    }
  });
```

but it doesn't work. Header doesn't appear. I found some header animations libraries that do this effect, but I want to implement it by simple jQuery code, don't want to use library.

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Are you getting any messages in your browser console?

Comment: Do you have that `header`element on your html ? it's fixed?

Comment: Yes I have that header. It has absolute position.

Comment: Hide and  show working fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for this effect to work your your header (if that's w) must be fixed so

```
header {
    position: fixed;
}
```

or you can add it to your jQuery like this

```
    jQuery(window).scroll(function () {
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() < 200) {
      $('header').css('position', 'absolute');
    } else {
      $('header').css('position', 'fixed');
      jQuery('header').show();
    }
  });
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I tried. Added position:fixed. It hide header, but it doesn't appear after 200px onScroll. :(

Comment: i tried the code and it's working, the only thing you can add is make the header hidden when the page loads

Comment: With position:fixed on the header, it should be working. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5requp5L/2/) for a working example. Can you provide the html/css for your header element?

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself well. I want to have header on beginning. Wen I start scrolling it hides because isn't fixed.  And the same header should appear after 200px scrolling.

Comment: I Edited my answer, please check if this is what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Glad i was able to help :)